# Clear browser frames using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is it possible to clear browser frames using javascript (found in Chrome). The reason I'm asking is because every time I logout and login back to the app it keeps the script files. I tried adding `` script.src = url + `?version=${+ Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}`; ``  so that it won't keep the cache but the frames below keep the scripts.

[image: image here]

Comment: have you tried disabling the cache in chrome dev tools?
https://www.webinstinct.com/faq/how-to-disable-browser-cache

Comment: Hi the cache is disabled but still doesn't work, i tried adding ```window.reload```,